# Deleting Order Items from Orders

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following JSON stored in mongodb

```
[
    {
        "orderItems": [
            "606808d2d7351b0c52d38634",
            "606808d2d7351b0c52d38635"
        ],
        "status": "Pending",
        "_id": "606808d2d7351b0c52d38636",
        "shippingAddress1": "Flowers Street , 45",
        "shippingAddress2": "1-B",
        "city": "Thessaloniki",
        "zip": "00000",
        "country": "Greece",
        "phone": "+00302410551416",
        "user": {
            "_id": "6062d46da91a58067da5dfc2",
            "name": "Vasilis",
            "id": "6062d46da91a58067da5dfc2"
        },
        "dateOrdered": "2021-04-03T06:18:58.879Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "606808d2d7351b0c52d38636"
    }
]
```

I can delete the order, no problem with that

```
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Order.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((order) => {
        if(order) {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'The order is deleted'
            })
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'order not found'
            })
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: err
        })
    })
})
```

Now I want to change the above code, so as to delete the orderItems as well. how to do that?

Thanks,
Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Model.deleteMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany) to delete the `OrderItem`s (I'm guessing that's the model name) after deleting the `Order` document. And you don't have to call `status(200)` on the response object since it's automatically set when calling [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json).

```
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const order = await Order.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    if (!order) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Order not found',
      })
    }

    await OrderItem.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: order.orderItems } })

    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Order deleted',
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: err,
    })
  }
})
```